# Почему блок не рендерится по всему своему размеру (Chrome)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, render

Накидал структуру и основные стили:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/8f130mpx/13/show/

На примере не проявляется баг.

Моя проблема в том, что сайдбар в реальном проекте судя по инспектору объектов доходит до конца, до самого футера, но визуально не дотянут до него. При этом часто по разному, а иногда и вовсе всё норм. Может не доходить до конца и 10px, и 300px (и явно выше 100% видимой области). Спасает, если прям в инспекторе уберу flex у sidebar, то всё станет прекрасно. В реальном проекте у меня ещё есть в контенте картинка карты, на которую если нажать она заменится на реальную карту, то есть произойдёт какой-то перерендер, после которого всё отображается корректно. Хотя если просто копировать-вставить какой-либо элемент прям в DOM, то проблема остаётся.

Вот скрин слоёв. При этом, напомню, в инспекторе показывается полная высота. И если мы в emulate css media поставим screen, то всё станит ок, даже если вернём на no emulation.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по всему это новшества 73 версии... в 72 не наблюдали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было этому сайдбару поставить min-height: 100%;. Кажется, хром иначе стал стандартизировать высоты Nested блокам во флексах